# Клик по элементу добавленному с appendTo

Tags: jquery, append

Здравствуйте.

Добавляю на страницу елементы с appendTo. Как имитировать клик по элементу, который добавлен с appendTo? `$('#result').live('click');` не работает. Говорят, что live устарел, on() лучше, но не работает.

```
$("#result div").live("click", function () {});
```

Просьба подсказать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотреть пример: http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/QLe8W/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var newBlock = '<div id="new_content">New content</div>';
// Добавили элемент
$(newBlock).appendTo('#container');
// устанавливаем обработчик нажатия кнопки мыши на элементе
$('#new_content').on('click', function(){
    alert('Ups!');
});
// вызовем событие нажатия на элемент (имитация)
$('#new_content').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Код приведен выше является антипаттерном, то есть избыток кода. Не нужно по многу обращаться к добавленному елементу.

Все это делается одной цепочкой

```
$('<div id="new_content">New content</div>').appendTo('#container').on('click', function(){/*YOUR ACTIONS*/});
```

Метод лайв действительно устарел, но его можно использовать и сейчас, потому как он в самой библиотеки основан на новом методе on.
Что бы использовать метод ОН вместо лайв, нужно событие ставить на БОДИ скажем, а сам обработчик уже на конкретный елемент. То есть использовать делегирование.

```
$('body').on('click', '#container', function(){})
```

Comment: Думаю, что вопрос вы прочитали не очень внимательно, т.к. ТС говорит об имитации события click. Посему, хотелось было бы интересно от вас услышать обоснованное заявление об избыточности кода. 


И лирическое отступление: старайтесь писать код без ошибок - **appenTo** и метода "лайв" не существует в природе. Есть метод, который читается, как "лив" (live).

Comment: Я больше чем уверен что вопрос задан в том направлении в котором ответил я. Так как автор не использовал бы live метод для ЭМУЛЯЦИИ если бы понимал о чем речь.
По поводу ошибок в тексте спасибо учту. Вы учтите свои ошибки в том коде который вы пишите, это намного важней, нежели упущена буква в методе!!!!