# Не ловится клик по элементу добавленному через append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Даже не знаю что еще добавить. Должно же работать.
Добавляю

```
<button class="delete_button">
```

Потом пытаюсь словить клик, и не ловится.

```js
let ebc = 0;

$('#add_block').click(function(){
    ebc+=1
    $('.add_block_block').append('<div id="ebc' + ebc + '">Какой то блок</div><div><button  class="delete_button" id="del' + ebc + '">Delete it</button></div>')
})

$('.delete_button').click(function(){
    let his_id = $(this).get('id');
    console.log('abrvalg');
    console.log('Need to delete ' + his_id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add_block_block">
                <p>Добавление полей</p>
                <button id='add_block'>Добавить блок</button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Клик вы вешаете на элемент, которого ещё нет на странице, поэтому на новых жлементах он не работает.  Выхода два

1. Вешать клик на элемент в той же функции,  что и добавляете.
2. Использовать делегирование:

   ```
   $(document).on('click', '.delete_button', function(){
    ....
   ```

Comment: Спасибо. Второй вариант рабочий. А можно подробнее о первом? 
Это оно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/115900/250046 ?

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то после `append` дописать `.on('click','.delete_button',function(){ ...` (возможно без второго аргумента). Тогда элемент будет добавляться и навешиваться слушатель на него