# получить (this).attr() за пределом функции jquery js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```
$('.post-load').click(function() {
   var post_number = $(this).attr('data-number');
   post_number += 2;
});
```

Надо получить `$(this).attr('data-number')` за пределами функции. Хочу +- что бы было так (но так не работает):

```
var post_number = $(this).attr('data-number');
$('.post-load').click(function() {
   post_number += 2;
});
```

Я бы с радостью сделал так - `$('.post-load').$(this).attr('data-number')`, но так нельзя : (

Comment: что ты в принципе пытаешься сделать?

Comment: пытаюсь получить уникальный `attr` элемента с классом `post-load` (так как у этих элементов attr разный) ну и потом при нажатии увеличивать эту цифру на 2 (`post_number += 2`). Ну и потом у меня ajax идет, который это всё обновляет (но это ни как не связано с получением уникального `attr`)

Comment: По логике было бы круто, если бы от эта строка кода - `$('.post-load').$(this).attr('data-number')`, работала. Но так как этот мой типо-разумный метод не работает, мне надо его заменить. И я прошу помощи у знатоков. (у вас)

Comment: так а почему this не устраивает? он делает то, что и надо - получает что-то у элемента, над которым произошло событие

Comment: Проблема в том, что если я в функцию вписываю `var post_number = $(this).attr('data-number');`, то при клике скрипт находит attr (допустим 1) и единожды прибавляет 2. И так только один раз. А если я вынесу этот attr за функцию, то при каждом нажатии будет прибавляться 2.

Comment: Понятно. Проблема в динамическом добавлении контента и слушателях на них....... тут это чинится банальным делегированием ........ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1402842/191482

Comment: в целом в дубликате вроде это есть